# search in a record in sql using only one word

Tags: java, mysql, swing, sqlite

I added a  search field and search button for searching a car from the database and put the result in a table and it works very fine but i want to search by one word only not the full text in the record for example in  Description  there are long text and i want to search for certain word without specifying that word in the code >> Could you help me please ???
the code:

```
public class SearchCar extends javax.swing.JFrame {

Connection conn;
ResultSet rs;
PreparedStatement pst;

/** Creates new form SearchCar */
public SearchBook() {

    super("Search");
    initComponents();
    conn = javaconnect.ConnecrDb();
}




 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
String sql="select * from CarType where Model=?";
    try{
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,jTextField2.getText());
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        rs.close();
        pst.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

    }
```

how to get it done?

Comment: Your question is unclear - please update with example records, example input, and expected result.

Comment: You mean you want to do a wildcard search? Then you will need prefix and/or suffix the search tern with `%`, you will need to do this at the time you bind the parameter

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible with sqlite to search for a word without specifying that word in the code in all tables, rows and columns of a database?